# how to disable all ui-selects in a form in angular1 app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

is there any way to find all ui-selects in a form and disable them?

Something like

```
angular.forEach(element.find('form')[0].elements, function(e) {
       e.disabled = true;
  });
```

but this does not affect selects.

ps: using fieldset is not an option.

Comment: can't you use ng-disabled?

Comment: no, there are just to many controls and they're built dynamically. Some parts of the form come from other systems so there is no way to add ng-disabled to all of them.